# How to create a dynamic root in Nginx based on a route value?

Tags: nginx

What I'm trying to accomplish is to be able to pass in a route such as this:

```
mysite.com/abc123/file.mp3
```

In Nginx I want it to read the abc123 and then call a piece of code (don't care what language: php, python, golang, fortran...) and then return the actual key that is needed to load the file.

In my config I have this:

```
server{
    #lots of basic stuff here

    location / {
        mp4;
        mp4_buffer_size        1m;
        mp4_max_buffer_size    5m;

        root /my_path/; 
    }
}
```

This works when I pass in my `abc123/file.mp3`. It will find the file and play it if that file exists in `/my_path/abc123/file.mp3`.

What I want is to translate (**from a database**) `abc123` to `myKey123` which would live at `/my_path/myKey123/file.mp3`

So, first, is this even possible?

If so, I'm not sure how to approach this. I know this question could have multiple solutions, but any direction will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

The PHP script can issue a redirection using the `X-Accel-Redirect` header. This is treated by `nginx` as an *internal redirect*, so the rewritten URI is not exposed to the user. The [documentation](https://www.nginx.com/resources/wiki/start/topics/examples/x-accel/) is a bit thin on details, hopefully you can find an example using PHP.

If you can ring-fence the rewritten URIs with a unique prefix, e.g. `/download/myKey123/file.mp3`, you can protect the files from direct access by using the `internal` directive. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#internal) for details. In which case, you will not need to obfuscate `myKey123`.

```
location /download/ {
    internal;
    ...
}
```